# paragraph with 'lead' bootstrap 4 class with button inside

Tags: bootstrap-4

In the Bootstrap 4 docs about Jumbotron they show in the example the following:

```
<p class="lead">
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
</p>
```

What is the need of a paragraph here?
And why use the 'lead' class? It seems to do nothing with the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lead` class makes the font stand out a little.

Here's the actual css rule set used for that:

```
.lead {
font-size: 1.25rem;
font-weight: 300;
}
```

Normal font-size on the body is:

```
font-size: 1rem;
font-weight: 400;
```

So, the `lead` class makes the font slightly larger and also a bit thinner which is what makes it stand out slightly.

Now, as far as the button is concerned, the `lead` class has absolutely no effect on the text inside the button. So, you are right in that the lead paragraph is not needed for the button.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#lead

Answer (score 3):

> "What is the need of a paragraph here?"

The `<p></p>` provides a new line and `margin-bottom` for the button.

> "And why use the 'lead' class?"

You're right, the `lead` class doesn't impact the button at all in this case. 
It's most likely unintentional, and carried over from the other `<p class="lead">..</p>` in the same [Jumbotron example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/).